# List Manager errors on any CSV Upload

Tags: list-manager

In Sitecore 8.1 List Manager (and confirmed in Sitecore 8.2), the List Manager CSV Import Wizard Dialog appears as though to throw an error, even though **no** error message box appears. The only way to notice that an error is occurring is that the upload dialog box is outlined in red and that the Next Button is not accessible.

[image: List Upload Erroring]

How do you fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Media Library there is a “List Manager” folder present in the Vanilla installation of Sitecore 8.1 Update-3.  You can plainly see it here:

[image]

If this folder goes missing, or is not present, the CSV Upload Wizard will error out like described in the question.

This situation occurred after an upgrade was completed in a stage environment, but then a package containing client media library items was "overwritten" removing this and some other **System** items.